# Grails: Internationalization from Java POJO

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm trying to use i18n Internationalization from a Java POJO that I've defined in `src/java/Gender.java` class.

**`Gender` Class:**

```
public enum Gender {

  NONE(0),
  MALE(1),
  FEMALE(2);

  private Integer code;

  Gender(final Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  Integer code() {
    return code;
  }

}
```

I'm trying to use some localized texts for each one of the enum's item, something like this (**the following code is not working!**):

```
public enum Gender {

  NONE(0, message("gender.none")),
  MALE(1, message("gender.male")),
  FEMALE(2, message("gender.female"));

  private Integer code;
  private String text;

  Gender(final Integer code, final String text) {
    this.code = code;
    this.text = text;
  }

  Integer code() {
    return code;
  }

  Integer text() {
    return text;
  }

}
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to use `messageSource` from a Java POJO?
I'm trying to avoid creating a table for gender.

**I'm using:**

- Grails 2.4.4

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toString()` method and `messageSource` bean to get the `enum` text value from `messages.properties`, like:

```
import grails.util.Holders;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;

public enum Gender {

    NONE(0, "none"),
    MALE(1, "male"),
    FEMALE(2, "female");

    MessageSource messageSource = (MessageSource) Holders.getApplicationContext().getBean("messageSource");
    private Integer code;
    private String text;

    Gender(final Integer code, final String text) {
        this.code = code;
        this.text = text;
    }

    Integer code() {
        return code;
    }

    String text() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        GrailsWebRequest webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest();
        return messageSource.getMessage("gender." + text, null, "default", webUtils.getLocale());
    }
}
```

where `messages.properties` have

```
gender.none=None
gender.male=Male
gender.female=Female
```